# Where can i find the option to use "multi master" in database mysql aurora creation

Tags: amazon-aurora

I try to find, how i can multi master configuration in aurora mysql, but i can not find it. I saw a Video to click on aurora and then on replication features, but i can not see it anymore in North Virginia.

see also:
[https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-aurora-multi-master-expands-availability-8-aws-regions/#:~:text=You%20can%20create%20an%20Aurora,effectiveness%20of%20open%20source%20databases](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-aurora-multi-master-expands-availability-8-aws-regions/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20create%20an%20Aurora,effectiveness%20of%20open%20source%20databases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-master was only available for Aurora MySQL 5.6, which is now deprecated [1]. This is also mentioned as a footnote in the launch announcement [2]. So it's not possible to create new multi-master clusters anymore.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.MySQL56.EOL.html
[2] https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/08/amazon-aurora-multimaster-now-generally-available/